# How to filter result by WHERE and then execute query on that?

Tags: mysql, sql

First I had a table `user_profiles` where users could have their own profile and I would use the following query to get all users who do not have a profile.

`user_profiles`

| id | user_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 4 |
| 3 | 7 |
| 4 | 6 |

```
SELECT * FROM users 
    LEFT JOIN user_profiles
    ON users.id = user_profiles.user_id
WHERE user_profiles.user_id IS NULL
```

Later on I added a `type` column since I didn't want to make dedicated table for each type, and since there could also be more types in the future. So I changed the table to:

`user_profiles`

| id | user_id | type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 4 | 2 |
| 3 | 2 | 2 |
| 4 | 4 | 1 |

So then I changed the query by adding an extra `WHERE` to the following:

```
SELECT * FROM users 
    LEFT JOIN user_profiles
    ON users.id = user_profiles.user_id
WHERE user_profiles.type = 1 OR user_profiles.user_id IS NULL
```

But it should be more like:

```
SELECT * FROM users 
    LEFT JOIN user_profiles
    ON users.id = user_profiles.user_id
WHERE user_profiles.type = 1 -- DO THIS FIRST
WHERE user_profiles.user_id IS NULL -- THEN THIS ON THE RESULT OF THE PREVIOUS
```

So basically I want to do the `WHERE user_profiles.user_id IS NULL` **AFTER** I did the `WHERE user_profiles.type = 1`. How could I achieve that in one query?

Is that possible and how could I achieve that with one query?

Comment: After? Simply AND the two conditions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want to filter on the second table in a `LEFT JOIN`, the condition should be in the `ON` clause:

```
SELECT u.*, up.*
FROM users u LEFT JOIN
     user_profiles up
     ON u.id = up.user_id AND up.type = 1;
```

Your version filtering in the `WHERE` clause is doing something else.  It is either returning users with no match or a match on `type = 1`.  It is not returning *all* users, with the information from `type = 1` if available.